# PHP Login Always Shows Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I am working on a custom PHP login for my webpage, Here is a snip-it of my code:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
if (!isset($action)) {
  echo '<h1>Login</h1><form role="form" action="?action=login" method="post"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"><input type="password" id="passwd" name="passwd" placeholder="Password"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></form><a href="?action=register">Register Here</a>';
}
else if ($action == "login") {
  $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
  if($stmt = $con -> prepare("SELECT *.* FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?"))     {
    $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, $passwd);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    if ($num_row == 1) {
      echo "Login Success!";
    }
    $stmt -> close();
  }
  else {
    echo 'Login Incorrect';
  }
}
```

I completed the registration successfully and the code inserts a new row into the mysql table. When logging in, I keep on getting an "login incorrect" error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Apart from the excellent answers I would like to add that the next time you are having trouble with query's, use: http://nl3.php.net/mysqli_error to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Also, don't store plaintext passwords

Comment: @RainFromHeaven, I was SHA256ing my passwords 6 times, but I thought that may have caused an error so I removed password hashing. I already added it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL statement is failing. That much is obvious because when your prepared statement fails it takes you to that error. That means your query is incorrect.

Looking at your query you are SELECTing `*.*` which is not valid syntax. It should just be `*`

```
SELECT *.* FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?
```

should become

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?
```

Comment: I guess I must have missed that. I was probably thinking it was a PHP-based error. I guess I was thinking about "GRANT *.*". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *.* FROM members
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM members
```